# tooltip once as 2 values are similar

Tags: angular, tooltip, apexcharts, ng-apexcharts

I Have a problem , can't make the tooltip display date one time only ,because  the date repeated [as image below the tool tip has 2 different values at the same time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3x6Z.png) ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3x6Z.png)

i tried  to add custom tooltip , but could not reach the best solution ,iexpect that i need to change something in tooltip's formatter

Comment: Hi. We need some code to troubleshoot with you / for you. Please edit your post and add what you have tried so far to resolve the error.